# Two way sync mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, bugzilla

I have a site A and site B. I want to install two bugzilla servers bugsiteA and bugsiteB and I want do two way database sync for both the sites A and B that way users can access all the data and same data in site A and site B.

Guide me the steps or share the documents which related to the above requirement.

My intention of this setup is now i already has bugzilla server in site A but whenever users try to access the bugzilla from site B it is slow because of ISP provider bandwidth usage. Thats the reason why I am asking above requirement.

Please share other better ideas for above requirement if already implemented in case same situation.

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 1):

This is known as Bidirectional replication (master-master replication), its depends on the db you are using. Plz also checkout golden gate.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication